# flush() does not flush on a Process OutputStream

Tags: java, process, io, stream, bufferedwriter

I tried multiple ways to do that: Printing to a process-outputstream with 1 second delay after each "flush()".
But flush doesn't seem to work as it's supposed to. Can someone tell me why? What I get is one combined `String` when "close()" is being called. There won't be printed anything before "close()" comes into action.

Context: This should shut down my minecraft server and run a backup afterwards.

```
    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
w.write("say Serverbackup begins in 3...");
w.flush();
Thread.sleep(1000);
w.write("say 2...");
w.flush();
Thread.sleep(1000);
w.write("say 1...");
w.flush();
Thread.sleep(1000);
w.write("say GAME OVER!!!!!!!!!!!!!...");
w.flush();
w.write("stop");
w.flush();
w.close();
process.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//...
```

Comment: What's the output of this code??

Comment: @SanketGupte It looks like this on the console: 
`say Serverbackup begins in 3...say 2...say 1...say GAME OVER!!!!!!!!!!!!!...stop`. One single string. "stop" would actually act as command, but it doesn't obviously since it gets connected to the rest.

Comment: Shouldn't it?? I mean, according to your code "stop" is treated as a string because you are passing it as a parameter to the write() method.

Comment: @SanketGupte Yeah it should. But as a "standalone" String. :) I need to print each "write" command separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Sanket Gupte answered, you have to add '\n' at the end of your messages,
since you read your process's input stream with .readline() (I suppose),
it will only print if a \n appears, regardless to your Thread.sleep(..) calls. And flush works as you supposed to. It writes the buffer to the stream.

- I suggest it is not a problem with the process, since I don't know
- what you are running in background I started bash and output via echo

  ```
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");
  processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
  try {
      final Process bash = processBuilder.start();
      BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bash.getOutputStream()));

      new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bash.getInputStream()));
              String line;
              try {
                  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                      System.out.println(line);
                  }
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }).start();
      bufferedWriter.write("echo say Serverbackup begins in 3...\n");
      bufferedWriter.flush();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      bufferedWriter.write("echo say 2\n");
      bufferedWriter.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

> Serverbackup begins in 3...

...(2 sec)

> say 2

Comment: Does this really work? That is exactly what I have, except for the "\n". But my messages won't be printed with the time delay between each print.

Comment: So why don't you just add "\n", as we wrote in the answers ?
This is the point I wanted you to explain.
If you don't add it at the end of your messages, there will be no "time delay".

Comment: java doc -> public String readLine():
Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Comment: Hm, this makes sense, wtf. I didn't try it because I wasn't on a computer when I wrote that. I will soon check if this solves my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks friend, it worked. I will accept this answer because it's the most specific one. I didn't know that the console actually works like this, I thought it would take everything it gets immediately and execute it, but that would make life hard for all the people that do not use buffered streams.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is, when you flush the code, it actually clears every data of what was last printed through the connection and cleans the channel through which connection is established. Hence, it keeps on appending the character on the same line. Add "\n" before and after each string. For example,
        w.write("\n say1...");
That would print each of your string on a separate line. This would print each string on a new line.

Comment: The problem is, that all of this is printed at once. But there is a "sleep" built in to wait 1 second after every "print". This doesn't work. It sleeps 3 seconds and prints everything at once afterwards.

Comment: Ok.. So you mean that the code is executing properly in background but it does not show the output in the desired manner, right???

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I think it's a better idea to put \n at the end of each command. Thanks for your help. :)